# How to find the corners of a 2D array such that it can be reliably and correctly rotated

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, image-rotation

I have an array called Existing_Array from a Geotiff LiDAR file, see screen shot below.

[image: Existing Unrotated 2D Array]

I am attempting to find a reliable way to rotate the image such that the side with the largest values (pink/red) is East facing and flush top to bottom.

my thought process is to use indexing to grab the `Top Right` and `Bottom Right` corners of the array using the below code snip.

```
for i, x in enumerate(Existing_Array[-1]):
    if x > 1:
        Bottom_Right = x
        
for i, x in reversed([*enumerate(Existing_Array[-1])]):
    if x > 1:
        Top_Right = x
```

Then calculate the angle between them and use that to apply a rotation to the whole array to get the below rotated array.

[image]

My issue is that using indexing doesn't always work because the 2D array could be drawn in a way that for example: The `Top Left` of the array could be at a lower or higher row/column index than the `Top Right` point that I am looking for, meaning the generic indexing code could grab that point instead and throw off the angle calculation to rotate the array to the below screenshot.

Is there a reliable way to calculate the angle between two points so I can orient the array as depicted in the screenshot if I do not know the shape of the array, only that the largest values will be to the right and the smallest values will be on the left?